# Is it possible Preload a form with Firestore values?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form that uploads its values to the Firestore database, and would  like to use the same component for updating the values, so the question might really be - how to load initial state according to a conditional whether the props are passed?

The form

```
import Servis from "./funkc/servisni";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ContactUpdate(props) {
  //
  console.log(props.item);
  //
  const initialState = {
    id: props.item.id,
    ime: props.item.Ime,
    prezime: props.item.Prezime,
    imeError: "",
    prezimeError: "",
    date: props.item.Datum,
    kontakt: props.item.Kontakt,
    kontaktError: "",
    published: true,
  };

  const [theItem, setTheItem] = useState(initialState);
  const [imeError, setImeError] = useState();
  const [prezimeError, setPrezimeError] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();

  const { item } = props;
  if (theItem.id !== item.id) {
    setTheItem(item);
  }

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setTheItem({ ...theItem, [name]: value });
  };

  const updatePublished = (status) => {
    Servis.update(theItem.id0, { published: status })
      .then(() => {
        setTheItem({ ...theItem, published: status });
        setMessage("The status was updated successfully!");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  const updateItem = () => {
    let data = {
      Ime: theItem.ime,
      Prezime: theItem.prezime,
      Kontakt: theItem.kontakt,
      Datum: theItem.date,
      published: true,
    };

    Servis.update(theItem.id, data)
      .then(() => {
        setMessage("The tutorial was updated successfully!");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  const deleteItem = () => {
    Servis.remove(theItem.id)
      .then(() => {
        props.refreshList();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  const validate = () => {
    let imeError = "";
    let kontaktError = "";

    if (!theItem.ime) {
      imeError = "obavezan unos imena!";
    }

    if (!theItem.kontakt) {
      imeError = "obavezan unos kontakta!";
    }

    if (kontaktError || imeError) {
      this.setState({ kontaktError, imeError });
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {theItem ? (
        <div className="edit-form">
          <h4>Kontakt</h4>
          <form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="ime">Ime</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                // id="title"
                name="ime"
                value={theItem.Ime}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="Prezime">Prezime</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                // id="description"
                name="Prezime"
                value={theItem.Prezime}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="Datum">Datum</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                // id="description"
                name="Datum"
                value={theItem.Datum}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="Kontakt">Kontakt</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                // id="description"
                name="Kontakt"
                value={theItem.Kontakt}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>
                <strong>Status:</strong>
              </label>
              {theItem.published ? "Published" : "Pending"}
            </div>
          </form>

          {theItem.published ? (
            <button onClick={() => updatePublished(false)}>UnPublish</button>
          ) : (
            <button onClick={() => updatePublished(true)}>Publish</button>
          )}

          <button onClick={deleteItem}>Delete</button>

          <button type="submit" onClick={updateItem}>
            Update
          </button>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <br />
          <p>Please click on a Tutorial...</p>
        </div>
      )}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The component passing the props:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function FireDetail({ match }) {
  console.log(match);
  console.log(match.params.id);
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();

  const getIt = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const docRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("polja")
      .doc(match.params.id)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        setItem(doc.data());
      });
    //
    console.log(docRef);
    //
    // const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("polja").doc("documentId")
    //
    setLoading(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getIt();
  }, [match]);

  if (loading) {
    return <h3>samo malo...</h3>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        {console.log("item: ", item)}
        Kontakt: tip - email
        <p> {item.Kontakt}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Datum rodjenja: {item.Datum}</p>
        {item.Prezime} {item.Ime}
      </div>
      <Link to={`/kontakt/update/${item.id}`}> ajd </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or you might have an alternative idea on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed it is

```
export default function ContactUpdate(props) {
  const initialState = {
    ime: props.item.Ime,
    prezime: props.item.Prezime,
    datum: props.item.Datum,
    kontakt: props.item.Kontakt,
    id: props.Id,
  };

  const [theItem, setTheItem] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTheItem(props.item);
  }, []);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setTheItem({ ...theItem, [name]: value });
    console.log(theItem);
  };

  const updateItem = (theItem) => {
    let data = {
      Ime: theItem.Ime,
      Prezime: theItem.Prezime,
      Kontakt: theItem.Kontakt,
      Datum: theItem.Datum,
    };
    console.log(updateItem());

    Servis.update(theItem.id, data)
      .then(() => {
        setMessage("Uspjesno ste izmijenili unos!");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  const deleteItem = () => {
    Servis.remove(theItem.id).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {console.log(("theItem", props, theItem))}
      {theItem ? (
        <div className="edit-form">
          <h4>Kontakt</h4>
          <form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="ime">Ime</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="Ime"
                value={theItem.Ime}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="prezime">Prezime</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="Prezime"
                value={theItem.Prezime}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="datum">Datum</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="Datum"
                value={theItem.Datum}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="kontakt">Kontakt</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="Kontakt"
                value={theItem.Kontakt}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>
                <strong>Status:</strong>
              </label>
            </div>
          </form>

          <button onClick={deleteItem}>Delete</button>

          <button type="submit" onClick={updateItem}>
            Update
          </button>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <br />
          <p>Odaberi jedan broj...</p>
        </div>
      )}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```